# When I updated Ubuntu it ask me to restart when I restart it then it say that Ubuntu has been blocked by current security

Tags: boot, unity, wireless, system-installation

When I updated my Ubuntu it ask me  to restart , when I restart it says Ubuntu has been blocked by current security policy then I click OK it say verification failed access denied then I click enter then it say default default boot device missing or boot failed insert recovery media and hit any key then select boot manager to choose a new boot device or recovery media then there is three option I click three but it say no bootable device -- please restart system plz help me

Comment: Disable Secure Boot at UEFI settings.

Comment: It not starting up how can I go to UEFI setting plz help me

Comment: You can disable secure boot in BIOS.

Comment: UEFI is the replacement of the old BIOS. Like BIOS, how to access it  varies (ESC, DEL, F8~F12, etc., etc.). Please check your user's manual.

Comment: I have lost my user manual I m using Lenovo E41 - 15 I don't now how to access BIOS please help me

Comment: According to [Lenovo support page](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500222), press F1 key when Lenovo logo is displayed.